# can the intel sense "xyzprinters 3dscanner" work on amd prossessors anyway?

Tags: 3d-design, scanning

i ordred a xyzprinter 3d scanner today on ebay, bechause i through it would work with my quick new windows 10 pc setup. but when i tested the scanner compability i downloaded here now, it says that all settings on my pc is compatible, but exept from the prosessor i have, the amd ryzen 7, 8 core. it says that my computer is not compatible with the xyz scanner bechause i have not the intel 4 or newer intel prosessor, but instead of having intel prosessor, i have an amd ryzen 7, 8 core prosessor. will the xyz 3d scanner work anyway, even if i have not intel but as quick as an old intel 4thgen prosessor is, i have an new amd ryzen 7, 8 core?

(i have also 32gb ram memory and nvidia 1070 mini graphic card with 8gb ram in and windows home 10 64bit and 3 usb 3.0 ports on my pc. and a corsair motherboard).

Answer (score 1):

Here are some ways a program might indicate incompatibility:

1. There is something in the code that is actually incompatible -- such
   as some Intel-only DSP instructions.
2. They are using an Intel library or source code that is licensed only for 
   use on Intel processors.
3. They added a check to their code to be sure the processor was
   powerful enough to handle the load, and they forgot to consider AMD
   or other processors.

Comment: ok. i ordered an xuzprinter 3d scanner. can it be that it can work on amd even when it uses intelsense tecnology to the depth sensor?

Comment: "Intelsense" doesn't appear to be an Intel Corporation trademark.  It might have nothing to do with the processor manufacturer.  I think all you can reasonably do it try it.

Comment: ok. ☺️ i try it when it comes next week.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. The answer should be a simple yes or no. You've listed some valid reasons why it might not work, but those are just guesses until we find someone who can confirm whether or not it will work.

Comment: I understand your point.  Should I have best either 1) not offered this information, or 2) added my non-answer as a comment, or 3) done something else?

Comment: I havent tried the scanner yet, bechause it never came in my mailbox last week. I only hope it comes this week.